# Alternative to long ifelse statements

Tags: r, if-statement

Say I have three individuals and I know the payment they require to enter different amounts of land into a scheme. I want to know how much land each participant would enter into the scheme for a given payment rate. I want them to enter the max amount they are willing for that payment rate. Previously I did this with a long ifelse statement, but that will not run inside a loop, so I'm looking for an alternative.

In this example, I've excluded a load of areas so it just presents as if participants can enter 50, 49 or 1 unit(s) of area.

```
paym_sh1a=200
paym_area_50 <- c(250, 150, 210)
paym_area_49 <- c(240, 130, 190)
paym_area_1 <- c(100, 20, 90)

 area_enrolled<- 
   ifelse(paym_area_50<paym_sh1a,50,ifelse(paym_area_49<paym_sh1a,49, 
 ifelse(paym_area_1<paym_sh1a,1,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table of your values:

```
paym_area = rbind(paym_area_50, paym_area_49, paym_area_1)
```

And then use vectorised operations more effectively. In particular, since your thresholds are decreasing, you could compare the whole table to the `sh1a` value, and count how many rows are below it:

```
(sums = colSums(paym_area < paym_sh1a))
# [1] 1 3 2
```

This vector can be used as an index into your results:

```
values = c(0, 50, 49, 1)
(result = values[sums + 1L])
# [1] 50  1 49
```